# Way to populate Logstash output variable without getting it from an Input?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is there another way to tell Logstash to supply a value to an **output** variable without pulling it from a Logstash input?  For example, in my case I'd like to create an Elasticsearch index based on a performance run ID (which I'd do from an external script) and then have Logstash send to that. For now I was thinking of creating a tcp input just for receiving perf run info and then have a filter to match on the run id. Seems like a convoluted way to do this though. For example:

```
input {
    tcp {
        type => "perfinfo"
        port => 8888
    }
}

if [type] == "perfinfo" {
    do some matching to extract the id
}

output {
    elasticsearch { 
        cluster => "mycluster" 
        manage_template => false 
        index => "%{id}-perftest" 
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if setting **manage_template** to false would actually be necessary. I've read that it is.

**Update**

Thanks Nirdesh for that. Using Ruby might be very handy.

While I was waiting I tried using a grok filter like so:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{WORD:perftype}-%{POSINT:perfid}" }
}
```

Which produced this stdout during debugging:

```
{
   "message" => "awperf-14",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-10-17T20:01:19.758Z",
      "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:33361",
      "type" => "perfinfo",
  "perftype" => "awperf",
    "perfid" => "14"
}
```

Which I tried creating an index based on this like so:

```
index => "%{perftype}-%{perfid}"
```

So when I passed 'awperf-14' to the input, I ended up creating these indexes

%{perftype}-%{perfid}

awperf-14

Which is not what I was expecting. Also, it's the %{perftype}-%{perfid} index that starts to be populated, not awperf-14, the one I actually wanted.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

You can add any no. of your own variables either for intermediate result or for permanent using a property called `add_field`. All most all filters in logstash support this property.

So, for your soluation, you can use a ruby script to find out the id dynamically and store it in a new variable called `id`, which you can use it in `output`.

For Example :

```
input {
   tcp {
       type => "perfinfo"
       port => 8888
   }
}

filter{
  if [type] == "perfinfo" {
    ruby{
         //do some processing
        add_field => { "id" => "Some value" }       
    }         
   }
}

output {
   elasticsearch { 
       cluster => "mycluster" 
       manage_template => false 
       index => "%{id}-perftest" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nirdesh, see my update above. I've also since tried adding a field and using that field as the variable, but I still have an issue where it creates two indexes. One index with the unevaluated variable name, and the other with the variable value. Not sure why it is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can do what I was trying to do via Logstash. To be a clearer, I simply wanted to change the index based on the performance run ID I'm executing. There's nothing in the data that would have this information (I have to pull it from a DB). So instead of trying to have Logstash listen for a performance run ID, I scripted this externally. The script uses the Elasticsearch API to create a new index, and then does a string replace for the index in the Logstash config file. It then restarts Logstash, which normally happens between performance runs anyway. This approach was much easier to do, and seems cleaner.